# How to change site from http://SERVER-IP/APP to http://SERVER-IP in Apache served Django website

Tags: django, apache, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have successfully deployed a Django Website in Google Cloud with the help of Bitnami serving using Apache.
The site is served at **http://SERVER-IP/APP**, how can i configure it to server from **http://SERVER-IP**?

Thanks

Comment: Which Google Cloud Product? How is that product configured?

Comment: hi i used the documentation at [https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/get-started-bitnami-django] to set up the server. The website is up and running from **ip-address/appname xx.xxx.xxx.xx/app** as it should. but i want it to run at **ip-address xx.xxx.xxx.xx** since to connect it to its domain in google i am using an *A* record that calls the server ip to serve data to the domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succeeded following this [documentation from bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/administration/redirect-custom-domains/) but using my domain name in the **ServerName** . awesome documentation by Bitnami, to make work easy read on 
[default apache configuration](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/administration/understand-config/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bnconfig tool to move the application to /. The following guide explains how:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/configuration/understand-bnconfig/

Comment: hi thank you for the reply, from the link i am supposed to open *cd /opt/bitnami/apps/APP-NAME* so going to the apps directory i only have one folder i can call which is *django* but my app is called *appet* located at  */opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/appet*